# how to tell if a stream has one pipeline or more?

Tags: java, java-stream

Can we say stream concat uses one stream pipeline? for example this code

```java
Stream.concat(
    l.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getCompanyState().startsWith("D"))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Company::getCompanyState)),
    l.stream()
        .filter(x -> !x.getCompanyState().startsWith("D"))
).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: If you had two pipes merging into one, would you consider it one pipeline?

Comment: @khelwood NO I wouldn't

Comment: This seems likely to be more an argument about the definition of "pipeline," not really about the Java code or how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way that you can tell that difference. Once you have concatenated two streams, you should think of the result as one stream no different from a stream created as one stream originally. Where a stream gets its elements from is always implementation dependent. In your example it may be quite clear that under the hood the stream probably gets its elements from two other streams, but there could be examples where this is far from clear-cut.

If your real problem is that your stream has been concatenated from streams having the same elements and you want to get rid of the duplicates, `distinct()` can do that. Consider for example:

```
    List<String> strings = List.of("C", "A");
    Stream<String> concatenated = Stream.concat(
            strings.stream().sorted(),
            strings.stream());
    String joined = concatenated.collect(Collectors.joining());
    System.out.println(joined);
```

Output has duplicates:

> ACCA

Solution: insert a call to `distinct()` into your pipeline:

```
    String joined = concatenated.distinct().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Now the output hasn’t got any duplicates

> AC

Comment: The first paragraph does answer the question (+1 for that) but I'm not sure how the suggestion to use `distinct` is relevant here. Combining with filters, `x.getCompanyState().startsWith("D")` and `!x.getCompanyState().startsWith("D")` will simply give `l.stream` and therefore, where `distinct` comes into picture is not clear to me.